# Change Text Alignment in UITableViewCell On Rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rotation, orientation

I am using sizing classes to turn two xib files (iPhone vs iPad) into one.  Most orientations have a 2x2 grid of UILabels above a UITextView.  However, for iPhone portrait, I want the UILabels to stack vertically.  I have this working great with sizing classes.  I was disappointed to see, however, that sizing classes don't allow for the change of text alignment.  Refer to my diagrams below.  In the main orientation I have the text in the yellow and blue UILabels right-aligned.  In the iPhone portrait orientation I want the same UILabels to have left-aligned text.  How can I change this if the user rotates the device while viewing these table cells?  I figure there's a better way of doing this than reloading the table.

[image: UITableViewCell Orientations]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to setup the text alignment based on the screen orientation or device. however you can create 2 labels, one with left aligned text and the other with whatever you're using otherwise, in a way that they are exclusive to the screen layout you're using. I.e. one label for iPhone and one label for everything else.

You can select then, for that UILabel object in storyboard, which screen layouts it will be installed for.

Comment: I considered doing this.  But the UILabels are IBOutlets and I can't figure out how to hook up both UILabels (which would be showing the same information) to the same IBOutlet.

Comment: In the same xib, there is no way to set up an IBOutlet for two views, even if they are in different size classes.  I would have to create an IBOutlet for each view, which is redundant.  It just seems like there should be a simpler, more elegant solution to this.

Comment: I agree there should be a more elegant solution. I did some research myself and I could not find anything that would say this was implemented for a 'storyboard only' solution - sometimes we still have to make concessions and write code for view (lookup for scrollviews + AutoLayout, thats a very famous one). You cant connect 1 IBOutlet to more than one view. But maybe your code could be smarter to setup more than one IBOutlet label text, at a certain time, if it'd make sense to build all the views in storyboard. I am voting up your question - it's good one and I'd be happy to see a solution